# Next Js 13 App Directory Not Showing Preview Images From Input To Uplaod

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, preview, next-images

I am trying to do a simple upload image layout on my app with a preview of the image. I followed a lot of tactics I found online either from Docs or YT Videos but none seem to work out. I get a weird behavior;
as soon as I upload an image the preview of my uploaded image is seen for <1 sec. and disappears. Here is my component:

```
export const ChangeBackgroundImage = () => {

const [files, setFiles] = React.useState<File | null>(null);
const [createObjectURL, setCreateObjectURL] = React.useState<any>(null);
const [src, setSrc] = React.useState<any>(null);

const uploadToClient = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    const i = event.target.files[0];

    setFiles(i);
    setCreateObjectURL(URL.createObjectURL(i));

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
       if (typeof reader.result === 'string') {
            console.log('Hello World');
            setSrc(reader.result);
        }
        return;
    }
        
    if (filesNew !== null) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(filesNew[0]);
    }
}
};

return (
    <div className={style.change_bg}>
        <h3>Change Background Image</h3>
        <p className={style.change_bg_descP}>
            Select A New Image And Upload It!
        </p>
        <div className={style.change_bg__form_div}>
            <UploadImageSVG width={40} height={40} color={Colors.blue_med} />
            {/* <input 
                type="file"
                accept='image/*'
                name='fileUpload'
                id='fileUpload'
                onChange={( event ) => {
                    // onFileChange(event);
                    if (event?.target?.files?.[0]) {
                        const file = event.target.files[0];
                        if (file && file.type.substring(0, 5) === "image") { setImage(file) }
                        else { setImage(null) }
                    }
                }}
                hidden
            /> */}
            <input type="file" name='image' accept='image/*' onChange={uploadToClient} />
        </div>

        <section className={style.handleImageDeletion}>
            <FolderSVG width={20} height={20} color={Colors.blue_med} />
            {src && <Image src={src} alt='Some Image' width={100} height={100} />}
            {src && console.log(src)}
            {files && files.name}
        </section>
    </div>
)
```

}

- Commented Input Also Produces the same problem on my browser.
- I even tried out a library; react-dropzone but also got the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Next JS Version: ^13.5.4,
React & React-Dom: 18.2.0

Comment: You can try this 
```
const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      if (typeof reader.result === 'string') {
        setSrc(reader.result);
      }
      return '';
    };
    if (files !== null) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it does not work either. I updated my question with the code you suggested embedded. It seems like the instant I upload any image (small or large) it gets deleted somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem myself. Posting it for someone else if they struggle.

Working on NextJS the problem was that in non-page components for some reason the file input does not work. I wanted to have a separate component for this action in my application. Eventually I just made a separate page to my application and works fine. This might be a bug or something, I don't know.

And the real problem was that even with the simple input:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange=[...] />
```

It was not registering the file. Kind of weird but ok.